# AppCompatTextView setTextSize ignored

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-support-library, android-appcompat

all, is this some kind of bug? Im trying to set same text size(min) for all AppCompatTextView's in layout, but manual setTextSize in just ignored by the view. And because of android studio bug I cant go to sources of support lib, any ideas why and what to do?

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes(autoScaleView, resources.getIntArray(R.array.autosize_text_sizes), TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP)

 <array name="autosize_text_sizes">
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>11</item>
        <item>12</item>
        <item>14</item>
        <item>16</item>
    </array>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="somedp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pricing_toggle_half_w"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/pricing_toggle_half_w"
    android:text="sometext"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `Invalidate Caches / Restart` or `clean project` and `Rebuild project` Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

--Use Spinner and relative layout or Linear Layout --

```
       <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:entries="@array/autosize_text_sizes"
        android:paddingStart="5dp" />
```